# URL to export to csv with parameters doesn't work anymore in Lightning whereas it works well within classic

Tags: lightning, reporting, data-export, urlhacking, csv

we use a url like this one to export data from a SFDC report to CSV, by sending parameters :

*https://www.salesforce.com/?pv0=123&pv2=1/1/2020&export=1&enc=ISO-8859-1&xf=localecsv*

where *pv0* and *pv1* are the 1st and 2nd criteria of the report we can change 'on the fly' in the URL

*&export=1&enc=ISO-8859-1&xf=localecsv* allows to obtain an export respecting the locale Date and Number settings

**Problem : this URL doesn't work in Lightning**

In Lightning we can :
change the parameters 'on the fly' with this kind of URL :

*https://lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report//view?fv0=123&fv1=1/1/2020*
pv replaced by fv

or export to CSV :

*https://www.salesforce.com/?export=1&enc=ISO-8859-1&xf=localecsv&isdtp=p1*

Do you know how to create an URL, compatible with lightning, and allowing parameters and export to CSV in the same URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone helped me on another forum.

Just need to update the URL to something like this.

https://www.salesforce.com/?pv0=123&pv1=1/1/2020&csv=1&exp=1&enc=UTF-8&isdtp=p1

So the URL used for Classic and the URL used for Lightning are not so different